# Content search web part is not displaying any result

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using business version of office 365 sharepoint 2016. The content search web part is not displaying any results. 
I want the content search web part to pull the result from the list library on the same page. The only thing I see is the label "Content Search" on my page. Please suggest as to what I need to do.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Please Go through with this link](https://sharesilver.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/content-search-web-part-for-specific-sharepoint-listlibrary/)

Create a search scope and give URL for your specific document library only in the rule.

Update: you need to create a Results Source and configure query to search in particular library only and configure your Search Results Web Part to use your Results Source.

[For More and clear Help](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/05/23/stage-10-configure-the-query-in-a-content-search-web-part-on-a-catalog-item-page/)